# How to change color of a word in UITextView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, core-text

Is it possible to change UITextView`s color in particular range or particular word? If a word appear more than once in a view then change the color of that word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem. I created subclass of UILable and UITextView used core text (CATextLayer) as a layer on label/textview and NSAttributedString will store all the information about the font and color

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use `NSAttributedString`. I recommend checking out AliSoftware's [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) which extends UILabel and adds support for setting text via NSAttributedString among other helpers. I'm using it in a current project and it's pretty fantastic.

Comment: Else WebView can be used where you have ability to change style partially :)