# Core Text setting default color and color of specific words

Tags: ios, colors, core-text

I'm pretty new to using Core Text, and I'm not finding much information on how to use the color attributes...  how would one set the default text color, then change colors for specific ranges?

What I'm trying to do is to draw a short sentence.  I'd like the default color of the text to be a light gray, and then to mark a single word in red to highlight it.

Comment: Check this amazing post on a blog http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/

Comment: heh that's the exact blog post I've been following, but thanks :)  and yes it is amazing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While trying to better explain the problem I was having, I found the error... I was doing this

```
UIColor _textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[string addAttribute:(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)_textColor range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

rather than this

```
UIColor _textColor = [UIColor grayColor];   
[string addAttribute:(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)_textColor.CGColor range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

It helps to make sure you're using the right sort of color object!

Answer (score 1):

There are two way to solve this problem

1)  I created subclass of UILable and UITextView used core text (CATextLayer) as a layer on label/textview and NSAttributedString will store all the information about the font and color

2) You'll need to use NSAttributedString. Check OHAttributedLabel which extends UILabel and adds support for setting text via NSAttributedString among other helpers.

Hope this will help.

For more information please cehck my post: [How to change color of a word in UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447466/how-to-change-color-of-a-word-in-uitextview)

Comment: I'm actually using NSAttributed string, but my problem that it seems like I can either set the color of the whole string, or I can leave it at the default and color individual sub-ranges.  I can't seem to do both, though.  I'll try and edit some of my code into the original question to better explain the problem I'm having...

Comment: Actually, nevermind... while editing in my code, I found the problem.  :)